# How to prove $\widehat{(fg)}(n) = \hat{f} (n) \ast \hat{g} (n); (n \in \mathbb Z)$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $f, g \in L^{1}(\mathbb T)= L^{1} ([-\pi, \pi))$. We define, the Fourier transform of $f$ as follows: 
$$\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{-int} dt, \ (n\in \mathbb Z).$$
It is well known that Fourier transform takes [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) to point wise product:indeed,by Fubini-Tonelli theorem and change of variable, we can derive,
$$\widehat{(f\ast g)}  (n) = \hat{f}(n) \cdot \hat{g} (n) ,  (n\in \mathbb Z).$$

Suppose $fg \in L^{1} (\mathbb T)$ also.

> **My question is**: To proving  $\widehat{(fg)}(n) = \hat{f} (n) \ast \hat{g} (n); (n \in \mathbb Z)$, the hypothesis $fg\in L^{1} (\mathbb T)$ is sufficient; and if yes, how to prove it ? (that is, under what conditions Fourier transform takes point wise multiplication to convolution product ) Or, we need to put some more conditions on $f$ and $g$ ?

**My attempt**: Fix $n\in \mathbb Z$.  By definition we have,  $\widehat{(fg)}((n)=  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} ( f(t)\cdot g(t) ) e^{-int} dt $  and 
$\hat{f}(n) \ast \hat{g} (n)= \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} \hat{f} (n-k) \hat{g} (k)
= \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} \{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{-i(n-k)t} dt \} \{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(y) e^{-ikt} dy\} $; from here I am stuck, ...;

Thanks,

Comment: You will probably have to replace one of f or g by its Fourier-series. I.e., you have to use that the Fourier-series represents the function in $L^1$. More fundamentally, this can be achieved by introducing an approximate identity like the Poisson kernel. Look up Karl Offner: "A little harmonic analysis" for a nice representation of details.